# Running a perl program under a debugger until some condition is met

Tags: c, eclipse, perl, debugging, epic

I am using perl debugger in Eclipse (via EPIC plugin). Is there any feature to automate the steps until an event occurs. For example can I make it run until $args->{some_arg} is set? If not, what is the best known workaround? This feature or workaround may be similar to debugging some other C-like languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for actually something that follows all the flow and stops whenever that condition is met. But closest thing to this is called conditional breakpoints which works as Leolo mentioned. EPIC actually supports this but some versions is kind'a faulty in some versions. The way to do that is after setting breakpoint somewhere, right-click on it and set condition in Properties dialog. In faulty versions, properties is the third choice in the menu, with no text.

[image: In faulty versions of EPIC, properties is the third choice in the menu, with no text.]

Answer (score 1):

In the normal perl debugger, setting `$DB::single = 1;` will drop you to the debugger.   So you could have the following:

```
  $DB::single = 1 if $args->{some_arg};
```

I have no idea if this works in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The stock perl debugger has a *watch* `w` command.

The perl debugger [Devel::Trepan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan) can also has a [watch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan::CmdProcessor::Command::Watch) command.

Here is an example. In file `test.pl`:

```
my $x = 1;
my $y = 2;
my $x = 3;
```

Now here is a sample session:

```
trepan.pl test.pl
-- main::(test.pl:1 @0x19b5da8)
my $x = 1;
(trepanpl): watch $y
Watch expression 1: $y set
$DB::D[0] = <undef>
(trepanpl): c
Watchpoint 1: $y changed
------------------------
old value   <undef>
new value   2
wa main::(test.pl:3 @0x1b2a5a8)
my $x = 3;
(trepanpl):
```

I should note one thing about watchpoints. In contrast to *gdb* which often has hardware support for this feature, that is not the case here. So when you use this, your program may slow down because the debugger gets called every each possible stopping point to check of the value of the expression has changed.

*Devel::Trepan* also has gdb-style breakpoints where you can attach a condition to the breakpoint. If using watchpoints slows your program down too much, use this which should be faster.

Perhaps someone will write an Eclipse plugin for *Devel::Trepan*.